# After installing .NET 5.0 SDK, `dotnet new` fails / errors out

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've installed .NET 5.0 SDK on macos 10.15.7 via the normal microsoft installer.

Running `dotnet --info` gives me the expcted:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  10.15
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.10.15-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

However, running `dotnet new` results in the following error.

```
System.IO.IOException: The system cannot open the device or file specified. : 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXX-dotnetcli-v5.0.100'
   at System.Threading.Mutex.CreateMutexCore(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name, Boolean& createdNew)
   at System.Threading.Mutex..ctor(Boolean initiallyOwned, String name)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.EnsureEntryMutex(String hivePath, ITemplateEngineHost host)
   at Microsoft.TemplateEngine.Cli.New3Command.Run(String commandName, ITemplateEngineHost host, ITelemetryLogger telemetryLogger, New3Callbacks callbacks, String[] args, String hivePath)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.New.NewCommandShim.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

(I've masked parts of the filename in the exception with `X` chars in case it is associated with a secret key on my machine. However, I honestly have no idea where the name is coming from. Maybe a commit hash for the release?)

I have verified that `dotnet` in usr/local/share/dotnet has correct ownership and is executable. Since the file exception does not give a path, I don't even know what file this is and why it cannot be accessed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you `dtruss` the `dotnet new`? And share what file it's trying to open?

Comment: Could it be a permission issue? See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36823

Comment: @omajid - Yep, that was it. Updated the permissions on `/tmp` and it works fine now. Thank you, kindly.